# dart function for viewing library functions and classes

Tags: dart

Is there a built-in DART function for showing the functions and classes in a specific library like the python dir,**doc** and help functions?

Answer (score 2):

The closest you can get is listing declarations with mirrors:

```dart
library testLib;

import "dart:mirrors";

class Foo {}

bar() => 10;

const baz = "Dart";

void main() {
  MirrorSystem ms = currentMirrorSystem();
  LibraryMirror lm = ms.findLibrary(#testLib);
  Map<Symbol, DeclarationMirror> declarations = lm.declarations;
  print("testLib declarations:");
  declarations.forEach((name, _) {
    print(MirrorSystem.getName(name));
  });

}
```

output:

> testLib declarations:
>     baz
>     Foo
>     main
>     bar

and you can reflect those declarations and get to their "guts"

**Take in mind that mirrors are slow and can bloat   dart2js output.**

Comment: How would I go about viewing the functions and classes for dart:io or dart:polymer using the above method?

Comment: @AloisNapitalai use full library name. For example, first import `dart:collection` and then use `#dart.collection`